# Multiple columns - filling left column first

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I have a multi-column screen displaying a bunch of div boxes using CSS.  I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to populate the left column first then flow into the next columns.

You will see that I have it set up to display 1, 2 or 3 columns depending on the screen width so I NEVER want to have horizontal scroll bars.  If you have a small display, only one or two columns are display and a vertical scroll bar appears properly.  If you maximize the screen, 3 columns appear, but the CSS "spreads" out the boxes across the columns instead of filling the first column.

Hopefully that makes sense.  Any help would be appreciated!

```css
<style>
    .Comment {
        width: 320px;
        height: calc(100vh - 40px);
        background-color: burlywood;
    }

    .CommentBodySurround {
        height: calc(100% - 40px);
        overflow: auto;
    }

    .CommentBody {
    }

    @media screen and (min-width:700px) {
        .Comment {
            width: 650px;
        }

        .CommentBodySurround {
            height: calc(100% - 40px);
        }

        .CommentBody {
            column-count: 2;
            width: 630px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width:1020px) {
        .Comment {
            width: 960px;
        }

        .CommentBodySurround {
            height: calc(100% - 40px);
        }

        .CommentBody {
            column-count: 3;
            width: 940px;
        }
    }

    .box {
        width: 290px;
        margin: 3px;
        border: 3px solid #345787;
        border-radius: 12px;
        display: inline-flex;
        background-color: #F1F1F2;
        height: 100px;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="Comment">
    <div style="height:30px; background-color:aquamarine">this is the top</div>
    <div class="CommentBodySurround">
        <div class="CommentBody">
            <div class="box">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                3
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                5
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                6
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                7
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                8
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                9
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                10
            </div>

            

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[How I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pIKC.jpg)

[I don't want the horizontal scroll bar if the screen is full, I want to scroll vertically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/algyj.jpg)

Comment: The issue is that it should fill the first column and then the next?

Comment: Forgot to mention that if you add  column-fill: auto; height: 100%; into the .CommentyBody styles, it almost works but displays horizontal scrollbars.  I only want vertical so if the content fills the screen it goes off the bottom....

Comment: I cannot seem to understand the desired result.. do you have a mock or a picture with what you want to achieve?

Comment: I added two pictures of how it should look.  Not sure why I got a down vote for asking a question and providing sample code.  :(

Comment: I'll take a look over them

Answer (score 3):

Set `height: 100%` and `column-fill: auto` to `.CommentBody`

```
.CommentBody {
  column-count: 2;
  column-fill: auto;
  width: 630px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

`column-fill: auto` makes it fill each column before passing to the next https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-fill

You need to set the height to 100% so it knows when it's actually completed.